# How can I determine the value of angle x in this figure.

Tags: geometry

[![I used geometry but Did not find the answer.  ][1]][1]

**I used Geometry but not avail **
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejxoz.jpg

N:B   The fiqure is a square.

Here is what I tred  - When using regular geometry I'm getting 4 equations with 4 variables but these 4 just result in expressing the variables in the form of other variables. Equations:- X+Y=115, X+W=135, Y+Z=90, W+Z=110[image]

Comment: Its a square. @Amaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've labelled a few points in the diagram; the angles in red should be trivial to find.
[image: Diagram 1]

Now, make a copy of $\triangle ABE$, and rotate it about $A$ until side $AB$ coincides with side $AD$.
[image: Diagram 2]

Now you just have to compare $ \triangle AE'F$ to $ \triangle AEF$. Do you see the rest?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Hint:**

Fold $\triangle ADE$ inside along line $DE$ and $\triangle CDF$ inside along line $DF$.

As $\angle ADE + \angle CDF = 45^0 = \angle EDF, \angle A = \angle C = 90^0 $ and $AD = CD$.

Where will points $A$ and $D$ meet and what does that tell about length $EF$ and about $\angle DEF$ wrt. $\angle DEA$?

Please ignore rest of the points and dotted lines. Those can be used to come up with another proof though.

Comment: Can you give figure of that square

Comment: But CDF is not a triangle

Comment: @ShaafiAhmedQazi I added a diagram.

Comment: @ShaafiAhmedQazi other than geometry, it can also be proven using law of sines.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw a circle in center A and passes vertex E. This circle also psses D which is base of altitude from A. In this case triangles ADC and ACE are equal because  AC is common side, AD and AE are radius of circle and CD=CE because they are tangents from C on the side BC. Therefore $\widehat {DAC}=\widehat{CAE}=25^o$ ,so $x=\widehat {ACD}=90-25=65^o$.